# Angularjs Fileupload change upload URL?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-fileupload

I use angular to upload the file as below :

If I run the following code, I get `403(Forbidden)`

```
var contextRoot = "http://localhost\\:6060/nomunoli";
...
...
uploadFile : function(taglist, description, userid, file) {
    return $upload.upload({
        url : contextRoot + "/auth/insertNMNL001FUN02",
        fields : {
            'description' : description,
            'userId' : userid,
            'tagList' : taglist,
        },
        file : file,
        fileFormDataName : 'file'
    });
},
...
```

In debugger console

```
POST http://localhost/:6060/nomunoli/auth/insertNMNL001FUN02 403 (Forbidden)
    b   @   angular.min.js:79
    s   @   angular.min.js:74
    c.$get.f    @   angular.min.js:71
    l.promise.then.J    @   angular.min.js:101
    (anonymous function)    @   angular.min.js:102
    a.$get.h.$eval  @   angular.min.js:113
    a.$get.h.$digest    @   angular.min.js:110
    a.$get.h.$apply @   angular.min.js:113
    (anonymous function)    @   angular.min.js:195
    n.event.dispatch    @   jquery-2.1.3.min.js:3
    n.event.add.r.handle    @   jquery-2.1.3.min.js:3
```

When I change the code as below, it is OK.

```
...
uploadFile : function(taglist, description, userid, file) {
    return $upload.upload({
        url : "http://localhost\\:6060/nomunoli/auth/insertNMNL001FUN02",
        fields : {
            'description' : description,
            'userId' : userid,
            'tagList' : taglist,
        },
        file : file,
        fileFormDataName : 'file'
    });
},
...
```

Comment: Two different types of slashes? You are using both `\` and `/` in your URL. Also, is there a slash required when specifying the port?

Comment: Yes, I need to specifying the port. Later, we will use `address:port`

Comment: One issue: There shouldn't be a slash between the domain (localhost) and the port (6060).

Comment: Later, I have to use global IP address and port to access the server side.